# SSIS packages - Error on importing data from SQL Server 2019 to MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

We are using a lot of SSIS packages to import data from SQL Server database to MySQL database on every day basis. We have used SQL Server 2012 and MySQL 5.0 earlier and all jobs worked fine. But we had to migrate to SQL Server 2019 based on licensing purposes. Also we decided to update our MySQL to version 8.0. And from this point we have some pain.

When developer executes any updated package on local PC or remote development server (throught Remote Desktop) - package works fine and all data migrates successfully from SQL Server 2019 to MySQL 8.0.

We deploy packages (I mean whole project) to Integration Services Catalog based on SQL Server. And if we run any upgraded package on server, we get an error: "Error: The number of columns is incorrect." on a validation phase:
[image]
(message order - from bottom to top)

Some of packages are very simple. They are also failed :(

Example steps of simple package:

1. Getting data from SQL Server 2019:

[image]

2. Then writing data to table in MySQL 8.0:

[image]

All columns are mapped correctly. There's no unmapped columns remain.

[image]

And right here comes an error.

So, we're wondering what's wrong, because all drivers on SSIS server and development machines are the same. We checked that MySQL DSN configuration between 5.0 and 8.0. They are the same.

We checked parameters twice and tried to build, run and deploy SSIS packages:

- from different developer PCs with VS 2019
- with fresh installation of VS 2019, SSDT and SSIS extension
- no parametrization of connection strings

We updated packages to use new TargetServerVersion - SQL Server 2019:
[image]

We installed MySQL ODBC Driver 8.00.26 on the new SQL Server 2019 (both x32 and x64 version). The same driver version is installed on developer PCs.

[image]

Outside of Integration Services Catalog packages runs normally. We refactored a few of them to run from a command-line with tool "dtexec". No errors appeared! But, imo, it's not the right way to execute SSIS, because there's no execution history, logs and proved scheduler. We're looking for possibility to execute all packages on SQL Server with standard functionaloty, not from command-line.

I will be glad for any help on my question.

Comment: What about SSIS Catalog project configuration? Right click on the project in the SSMS Object Explorer, and select  'Configure...'

Comment: Which options there do you mean? There's only parameters and references to environments. We use parameters and environments only for storing connection strings for different technical landscapes. They works fine on execution of packages, we see correct parameters in Execution history log.

Comment: It is very possible that SSIS run-time environment configurations are pointing to the 'wrong' mysql environment where its schema is different from the mysql dev. environment. That could be a reason for an error: "Error: The number of columns is incorrect." on a validation phase.

Comment: @Arseniy Check the protection level of the package and project? if they are different it might cause the problem. Also try setting the "Delay Validation" = True.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we figured out this issue. It took so long because developers don't have access to the server configuration to check connection properties. Firstly, the trouble was in ODBC Data source configuration, where the wrong Database was choosen. Secondary, we use short connections string, like "Dsn=OdbcConnectionName", where "OdbcConnectionName" is ODBC connection name from ODBC Data Sources.

Some tables between two databases are the same, so we thought that we are in the right database. After we got screenshot from administrators, we realized that connections was wrong.

Here's the field, that was wrong.

[image]